# Regex for converting \eqref{*} to (\ref{*}) in Latex by Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am writing a paper using Latex, where lots of **\eqref{}** in it, such as  **\eqref{e1}** and **\eqref{e2}**. While the aim journal wants me to use **(\ref{})** to replace all **\eqref{}**. Then I want to do this by using the regex in Notepad++. Any help?

Comment: Why do you even need regex for this? That's a simple replacement where you replace `\eqref` by `\ref`. Or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Thank you for replying@csabinho   In fact, I want change, say \eqref{e1}, to (\ref{e1}), not just \ref{e1} . Note the parentheses.

Comment: OK, that replacement would need two steps without RegEx, not just one. So at least it's a bit useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (?<!\S)\\eqref(\{[^}]*\})
Replace: (\ref$1)
```

### Demo

Comment: It is helpful @Tim Biegeleisen In fact, I want change, say \eqref{e1}, to (\ref{e1}), not just \ref{e1} . Note the parentheses.

Comment: Wow, it is amazing! Vielen Dank@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\eqref({.*?})`
- Replace with: `\(\\ref$1\)`  Note: backslash and parenthesis MUST be escaped in replacement
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\              # a backslash, must be escaped
eqref           # literally
(               # start group 1
  {             # opening curly bracket
  .*?           # 0 or more any character, not greedy
  }             # closing curly brakcet
)
```

**Replacement:**

```
\(              # opening parenthesis, must be escaped in Notepad++
\\              # a basckslash, must ne escaped
ref             # literally
$1              # content of group 1
\)              # closing parenthesis, must be escaped in Notepad++
```

**Given:**

```
I am writing a paper using Latex, where lots of \eqref{} in it, such as \eqref{e1} and \eqref{e2}.
```

**Result for given example:**

```
I am writing a paper using Latex, where lots of (\ref{}) in it, such as (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}).
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @Toto In fact, I want change, say \eqref{e1}, to (\ref{e1}), not just \ref{e1} . Note the parentheses.

Comment: @JohnStone: See my edit. Note that backslash and parenthesis **must be escaped** in Notepad++ replacement part.